# Get a select option/element by name and pass it in an input field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the `select` below and I want to pass its selected value based on the option's name `(color)`, inside an input field using jQuery but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select_color_id option[name="color"]').on('change', function() {
    var selectedoption = $('#select_color_id').val();
    $('#search-query').val(selectedoption);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
  <input type="text" id="search-query" class="search-color-field" name="search_query" placeholder="Search your color...">
</div>

<select class="form-control" id="select_color_id">
  <option value="white" name="color">White</option>
  <option value="black" name="color">Black</option>
  <option value="red" name="color">Red</option>
  <option value="brown" name="color">Brown</option>
  <option value="pink" name="color">Pink</option>
  <option value="search-add" name="new-color">Add new color</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The `change` event is fired on the select, not the option. Remove ` option[name="color"]` from your selector and the code will work correctly.

Comment: I see but how can i pass in the input field only the options that have the name (color)?

Comment: Will you have multiple options that aren't a "color"? Or just the single "new-color" option that you want to avoid?

Comment: All options will have the name (color) except the last one so I just want to avoid the "new-color" option (i will fire other event when this option is selected).

Answer (score 0):

First `option` tag does not have `change` event. But you can get selected option and check the name to see if it is `color` or not:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select_color_id').on('change', function(e) {
     var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected")[0];
     console.log(optionSelected.getAttribute("name"))
     
     if(optionSelected.getAttribute("name") === "color"){ 
         var selectedoption = $('#select_color_id').val();
         $('#search-query').val(selectedoption);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
  <input type="text" id="search-query" class="search-color-field" name="search_query" placeholder="Search your color...">
</div>

<select class="form-control" id="select_color_id">
  <option value="white" name="color">White</option>
  <option value="black" name="color">Black</option>
  <option value="red" name="color">Red</option>
  <option value="brown" name="color">Brown</option>
  <option value="pink" name="color">Pink</option>
  <option value="search-add" name="new-color">Add new color</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `search-add` is always going to be the only thing you don't want to appear then you can just do a check for it, then otherwise set the value of your `search-query` input field to your `selectedoption` variable:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select_color_id').on('change', function() {
    var selectedoption = $('#select_color_id').val();
    if (selectedoption == 'search-add') {
      return;
    }
    $('#search-query').val(selectedoption);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
  <input type="text" id="search-query" class="search-color-field" name="search_query" placeholder="Search your color...">
</div>

<select class="form-control" id="select_color_id">
  <option value="white" name="color">White</option>
  <option value="black" name="color">Black</option>
  <option value="red" name="color">Red</option>
  <option value="brown" name="color">Brown</option>
  <option value="pink" name="color">Pink</option>
  <option value="search-add" name="new-color">Add new color</option>
</select>
```